# Percona db Replication Issue

Tags: mysql, replication, percona

One master Server
3 slaves

Master Server version: 5.5.24-55-log

1st slave Server version: 5.5.24-55

2nd Slave Server version: 5.5.24-55

3rd slave Server version: 5.5.25a-27.1

On the first two slaves,the following type of statements get replicated properly
insert into table1 (select * from table 2) 
insert into db2.table1(select * from table2)

On slave 3 (with newer version of percona db), the statements seem to fail

all of the slaves have same my.cnf file with only server_id different.

could this be a bug in the new version of the software.

I have tried uninstalling the slave and then resyncing it using latest data from the master.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Issue
1. The timezone on the slave was different to all other machines
2. this differnce in time ,caused some of the queries to not work properly as the queries were using the mysql NOW function